# How to use entititymanager.getReference() to return the object based on unique value?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a requirement to use entityManager to get the object based on the unique value.
that is:

```
EntityManager em;

bizObj.setCustomer(em.getReference(Customer.class , customerId));  //This works
```

Can I do as follows: (Say `customerCode` is unique), I want to retrieve based on **customercode**

```
// Assume code is unique
entity.setCustomer(em.getReference(Customer.class , customerCode);
```

Comment: Yes it would. Why dont you give it a try?

Comment: @SMA, I thought this work based on primaryKeys, Not like that?

Comment: @SMA I tried, But getting,  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.abc.core.model.Company. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.String
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getReference(SessionImpl.java:3405)

Comment: So its a wrong type i assumed it was of same type and you would get exception. What is that you are expecting?

Comment: @SMA Here, CustomerID is Long type and that is the primary key, But customer code is a string value but it is unique. I want to get Customer  entry stored in the DB, using customer code. Is that possible?